# CircularProgressIndicator value not updated

Tags: flutter, flutter-circularprogressindicator

For the code shown below, I think that just calculating a new value for `_progress` should cause the CircularProgressIndicator to redraw.  That does not appear to be happening.  It never updates, although I have verified in the debugger that `_progress` *is* changed.

What do I need to do to get it to update?

```
      int completed = 0;
      int total = list.length;
      double _progress = 0;

      showDialog(context: this.context, builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Downloading ...'),
          content: CircularProgressIndicator(
            value: _progress));
      });
      for (FileInfo fileInfo in list) {
        if(fileInfo.publicUrl != null) {
          var filename = dir!.path + '/' + fileInfo.name!;
          await dio.download(fileInfo.publicUrl!, filename);
          completed++;
          _progress = completed/total;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `CircularProgressIndicator` is not updating because the widget tree is not being notified of the changes in the `_progress` variable. Simply changing the value of a variable does not automatically cause the widgets to redraw. You need to inform the framework that a change has occurred and that it needs to rebuild the relevant widgets.

A solution is to wrap the `AlertDialog`  in a `StatefulBuilder`  and call `setState` after updating the `_progress` variable.

First ensure that the code you provided is in a `StatefulWidget`, then make changes as shown below:

```dart
int completed = 0;
int total = list.length;
double _progress = 0;

showDialog(context: this.context, builder: (BuildContext context) {
  return StatefulBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Downloading ...'),
        content: CircularProgressIndicator(value: _progress),
      );
    },
  );
});

for (FileInfo fileInfo in list) {
  if(fileInfo.publicUrl != null) {
    var filename = dir!.path + '/' + fileInfo.name!;
    await dio.download(fileInfo.publicUrl!, filename);
    completed++;
    setState(() {
      _progress = completed / total;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  All the examples I saw didn't really show any mechanism for the update.  I thought maybe Flutter was doing some "behind the scenes" magic that everyone seemed to know but me.